# Changing the background color of tkinter ttk.Frame in python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I was using tkinter to create a simple application, and wrote the following code to try and change the background color of the Frame I created. However, when I run the code I can only see grey background. I am using MacOS if that is any relevant.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

root.title("Hangman")

style = ttk.Style()
print(style.lookup("Tframe", "background"))
style.configure("TFrame", background="red")
        
startframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12", width=800, height=500, style="TFrame")
startframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

I tried using foreground instead of background without any luck.

UPDATE: I tried the same code on Windows and it worked without any issues. It seems like it is somehow related to my environment. Any ideas on why this might be happening would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to reinstall Python from python.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows the ttk widgets are drawn using style elements provided by the Windows theme engine. If is not intended that you change the background but that you get to use the system provided theme background. With the vista element engine Tk doesn't actually draw the elements - the Windows theming engine draws it at the position and size specified by Tk. Some other themes use Tk drawing operations and so can be configured using style configuration (basically all except the vista theme and the macos theme).

You *can* create a new style for a ttk Frame in the vista theme that uses elements from one of the other styles (like "default") and create a new style layout that draws using Tk functions. Or you can use the original tk Frame. If you use `style.layout("TFrame")`

Here's an example to try that creates a green ttk frame and ensures this works for any theme. It does what I've described above creating a new layout using a Tk drawn element to replace the vista style-engine provided border element.

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

def createGreenFrame(style):
    if "Green.border" not in style.element_names():
        style.element_create("Green.border", "from", "default")
        style.layout("Green.TFrame", [
            ("Green.border", {'sticky': 'nswe'})
        ])
        style.configure("Green.TFrame", background="green")

def switchTheme(ev, style):
    style.theme_use(ev.widget.get())
    createGreenFrame(style)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    style = ttk.Style()
    createGreenFrame(style)

    base = ttk.Frame(root)
    
    label = ttk.Label(base, text="Themes: ")
    themes = ttk.Combobox(base, values=style.theme_names())
    themes.set(style.theme_use())
    themes.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda ev: switchTheme(ev, style))
        
    frame = ttk.Frame(base, width=100, height=100, style="Green.TFrame")
    
    label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nw", padx=2, pady=2)
    themes.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nwe", padx=2, pady=2)
    frame.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
    
    base.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    base.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

    base.place(relwidth=1.0, relheight=1.0)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the Frame Class from the tkinter module inseted of ttk

```py
startframe = Frame(root, width=800, height=500, background='red')
```

Comment: That solves the problem, but I don't exactly get why ttk frame wouldn't work